# Keeping UINavigationBar on top when programatically calling a segue

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have an application that links to a view via a button (which is embedded inside a navigation controller)

Which all works fine! I hit the button and the view is presented using **Segue Show Eg: Push**. The view pops over and I see a UINavigationBar with my title and a button to dismiss.

My question is.. I need to programatically call this view again in my code, however, when I do this the view appears without any UINavigation. I assume it does this because it's no no longer embedded inside the UINavigationController?

Whats the best solution for this? Should I programatically create the UINavigationBarController? If so how would this look in swift?

Thank in advanced.

```
// Code below is triggered from an action (button) on UIAlertController.
// This loads up the "Scan Barcode view" without the UINavigationBar embedded.
let scannerViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ScannerViewController") as ScannerViewController
self.presentViewController(scannerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

When I set up the connection using interface builder from another button (located elsewhere) so show the same view. It works perfectly showing the "Scan Barcode" embedded inside the Navigation Controller.

[image: Image of interface builder]

When using interface builder to link (from the camera button) it works perfect.

[image: Image of interface builder again]

Comment: Do you mean you're going back to the view that has the button or the view that the button is showing?

Comment: No the button was an example for being able to load the "Scan Barcode" view form another view (for example). Whilst being embedded in the UINavigationController. So initially this was done by linking the button up with the NavigationController in interface builder. But you can't do this in the code right?

Comment: So when is it not working? When you're programmatically trying to segue as opposed to using the button's IBAction? Can you show the code of both?

Comment: Yeah sure.. The button way works perfect as it points to the "Navigation Controller" you see in the image. But when programatically calling it (ScannerViewController which is "Scan Barcode"), it doesn't work :(

Comment: You posted one snippet. Please post the other and label both of them appropriately. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. I don't know storyboards super well, but I do know that you're going to want to use the `pushViewController` on your navigation controller to show the new view to get it to keep the navigation bar. However, I'm pretty sure there's a specific storyboard method for maintaining the stack if you're using those, so you'll probably want to do a little research and find that first.

Comment: Cheers buddy :) I'll have a play around and see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @kpsharp the solution was just to use

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(scannerViewController, animated: true)
```